# Using Regex lookaround to insert HTML into string in specific location

Tags: php, html, regex, regex-lookarounds

I am working with an automatically generated HTML menu (generated by WordPress) and I'm trying to use preg_replace and regex lookaround techniques to insert an HTML snippet into specific locations within the menu code.

I am very new to using regex to make matches. I tried using a combination of lookahead and lookbehind to match a specific location in the menu code and have had some trouble getting it to appear in the exact spot I want.

Here is what I have so far: https://regex101.com/r/thq6rK/1

```
(?=<\/li><li id=.*?mega-menu )
```

The HTML menu code is in the example regex101 editor and if I'm correct, there should only be one match (even though there are two instances of class="mega-menu" being used in the HTML.

I'm trying to locate the spot right before the each instance of `<li>'s` with the class "mega-menu" and insert a custom `<div class="custom-class"></div>` directly before the preceding closed .

I am sorry, it's a bit hard to explain. Here is an example.

The chunk I'm interested in:

```
</li></ul></li></ul></li><li id="menu-item-26880" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children mega-menu has-picture has-picture-2 menu-item-26880 nav-item">
```

How I want to work (the line breaks are just to better show the inserted `<div>`):

```
</li></ul></li></ul>
<div class="custom-class">This would be inserted</div>
</li><li id="menu-item-26880" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children mega-menu has-picture has-picture-2 menu-item-26880 nav-item">
```

Thank you for any help you may be able to give me.

Comment: It would be better to use `DomDocument` to parse the HTML and update the document, rather than doing regexp replacement.

Comment: I was using that for part of my mega-menu and couldn't figure it out for this last bit that I'm trying to use regex for above (also first time trying to use DOMDocument). I'll give it another shot, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close. Change `.*?` to `[^>]*` so it won't match across multiple elements.

You think that using a non-greedy regexp should make it find the shortest match. But greediness only applies on the right, not the left. `*` starts matching as soon as it can; when it's greedy, it matches the longest repetition that's consistent with the rest of the pattern, when it's non-greedy it matches the shortest repetition.

https://regex101.com/r/thq6rK/2

Comment: Thank you for your help. Much appreciated. I'll give DOMDocument another look too.